# Is there JDK interface which looks like interface ConsumerInterface<T> { void consume(T data); }

Tags: java

There's `Callable<V>` in JDK which is producer interface, is there consumer interface in JDK?

Question rationale: I'm writing executor which accepts 2-phase tasks: 1st phase is producing data, 2nd phase is consuming of that data. In between these 2 phases I could like to cancel task (i.e., to not performing consumption).

**UPDATE**: Well, I thought such general-purpose interface (e.g., useful in multi-threaded programming) could be in JDK. I just can't remember if I actually seen such interface in JDK.

Comment: Does it have to be part of the JRE, or can it be part of an external 3rd-party library?

Comment: Well, I thought such general-purpose interface (e.g., useful in multi-threaded programming) could be in JDK. I just can't remember if I actually seen such interface in JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled by writing my own interface.